# Is there a common way to decribe voxels and greyvalues in formulars

Tags: image-processing

I need to write a report about some image processing topic. I want to describe some kind of density, e.g:

$\rho = \frac{\text{voxels with greyvalue 128}}{\text{number of voxels}}$.

Is there a common way how to describe this in a more mathematical sense? I would use for example the cardinality symbol and define some function for the voxels:

$\rho = \frac{|V_{128}|}{|V|}$.

denoting $V$ as the Voxels.
But in my opinion the $V_{128}$ looks terrible and unintuitive.

In one publication I read for example $o(128)$ where $o$ is a function of greyvalues.
But I think this is also not commonly used?

(This question might be off-topic here. I'm not sure :/)

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! Indeed you might get better answers at http://dsp.stackexchange.com, which is devoted to signal and image processing. But as long as you clearly define your notation and stick to it consistently, there is nothing wrong mathematically with what you're proposing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply a question of notation. Let's say you have previously defined $V_{128}$ as the set
$$
  V_i = \{k : v_k=i\}
$$
(in other words, as the set of *indices* $k$ for which the $k$th voxel value $v_k$ equals $i$), then $|V_i|$ is clearly the size of the set -- in other words, the number of voxels with the desired grayscale value. The point is that you must make clear beforehand that $V_i$ is a set, and then writing $|V_i|$ makes sense.

Other notations would use $\#V_i$ to denote the number of elements of a set, which is of course the same as the size of the set.

Comment: but then the definiton should be $V_i  = \{k: v_k = i\}$, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. Fixed.